# Error syntax for adding a foreign key to a table from a another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to alter a table by the name `inventory`, adding a column named `ProductCode` of type `int`. This is syntax I am using and keep getting error in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
ALTER TABLE Inventory
    ADD ProductCode INT NOT NULL;

ADD FOREIGN KEY (ProductCode) 
    REFERENCES Product(ProductCode)
    CONSTRAINT fk_inventory_product;
```

This is the error message I keep getting

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'.

I have also tried

```
ALTER TABLE Inventory
    ADD ProductCode INT NOT NULL;

ADD CONSTRAINT fk_inventory_product 
    FOREIGN KEY (ProductCode) REFERENCES Product(ProductCode)
```

but I get the same error.

Any guidance would be appreciate as everywhere I look online says this syntax is correct will upload picture for reference.

[image]

Comment: This looks like for `Microsoft SQL Server`. Please remove `MySQL` tag

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors.

Comment: Please read the documentation, as what you have used is not correct.

Comment: You want the tsql tag, because this is SQL server specific syntax.

Comment: Your second version is almost correct, `ADD CONSTRAINT fk_inventory_product FOREIGN KEY (ProductCode) REFERENCES Product(ProductCode)`. But to which table should SQL Server add it?

Comment: Execute ALTER TABLE BlaBlaBla ADD CONSTRAINT BlaBlaBla ...

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is indeed a bit off - try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Inventory
    ADD ProductCode INT NOT NULL      -- add column - do *NOT* terminate  with ";"
        CONSTRAINT fk_inventory_product   -- add FK constraint
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(ProductCode);
```